# Apache Camel, JMS over SOAP

Tags: spring, soap, apache-camel, jms, activemq-classic

I want to make make the following architecture:

1. Client calls SOAP service A
2. A calls service B
3. B calls service C
4. C return result to A
5. A gets the result and sends reply to client

**Special condition: reply from C couldn't be meditated to B**

[image]

Due to this special restriction, chain of synchronous SOAP calls is out of question. Is it possible to implement this using Apache Camel? My initial thought for this is using two message queues:

- Message queue for request from A to B
- Message queue for responses from C to A

In the other hand, RPC from B to C could be one-way SOAP request or any mechanism, which is easy to implement and maintain. Each service instance could use Apache Camel as integration layer. But there is a problem, how do I make the "JMS callback" jump over to service C.

For now, I have defined routes for service A

```
    <route id="cxfToJMSRoute">
        <from uri="cxf:bean:endpoint" />>
        <convertBodyTo type="String"/>
        <to uri="activemq:queue:api?replyTo=result&amp;replyToType=Exclusive" pattern="InOut" />
        <transform>
            <simple>Hello ${in.body}</simple>
        </transform>
    </route>
```

And service B

```
  <route id="apiToServiceARoute">
      <from uri="activemq:queue:api"/>
      <transform>
        <simple>Hello ${in.body}</simple>
      </transform>
  </route>
```

This just echoes the message between two services using the request and response queues.

But how I can add the third service C, such that service B route will call service C, and **it is service C, which will send the reply to A's reply queue**. Service B should actually return nothing. How do I connect things together declaratively using Camel?

Is it even possible to implement this using Camel DSL abstractions, or do I have to implement the mechanism myself? Could I, for example utilize aggregator EIP in this case?

Comment: Is there a reason you need Service B at all? Seems a bit strange you have a service in the middle but C should respond to A directly?

Comment: Service B is vital. Both services will enrich the data, but they has to be completely decoupled and individually auditable/administrable, and actually resides in different network segments. Separation of concerns for confidentiality. Let's call this a two-phase processing. For A and B the two-phase processing must be transparent. In other words, from A or B point of view, the existence of C is not known, but it still intercepts all the messages.

Comment: Well you could use JMS or RabbitMQ for this. Basically Service A calls Service B via JMS/Rabbit and sets its replyTo queue. Service B calls Service C but rather than create a new reply to it sets the reply to from what was given from Service A.

Comment: I guess you need to worry about timeouts on all the services.

Comment: Doesn't camel handle timeouts automatically to some extend? When I use `uri="activemq:queue:foo"` with `InOut` pattern, exception is thrown, if reply doesn't arrive in time. But how can I ensure these undelivered messages **won't be persisted** in queues after the timeout? After all, for the client, service is synchronous, and those "lost" messages wouldn't have any context anymore, when the client receives the fault

Comment: The queues created are temporary queues, at least that is how it should be. The queues are just there whilst the process is waiting for a response. If no response is returned the queue is removed. No messages can arrive to that queue afterwards.